# Sonarqube throws Review this usage of "array" as it can only be empty here

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I'm working on a react project and I have the following code.

```
const productsData = [];
const resultArray = map(arr, currentIndex => {
   // some logic
});

return productsData.concat(...resultArray);
```

Now in sonarqube, the return statement throws `Review this usage of "productsData" as it can only be empty here`.

My approach to solve this would be `return [...productsData, ...resultArray]`.

Any thoughts on the solution?

Comment: Is the the *actual* code sonarqube is reviewing? What is `map`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes it's reviewing actual code. map is iterating based on business logic

Comment: Ok, seems you should probably update your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: maybe this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask for reviews?